# Add skills tests to Stack Overflow Careers

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

Stack Overflow Careers would be much better with a skills test section. This would demonstrate a person's programming ability.

I know quite a few successful companies that do this. Most notably are Odesk and Hired.com.

There are a couple security measures that can be added to ensure fair play

- Allow only one attempt at a test every month
- Generate random questions from a RNG
- Disable clicking outside the test window

This would be a great feature for SOC

Comment: HEre's a gist w the answers 2 the skewls test!  lol k thx bai!

Comment: *"There are a couple security measures that can be added to ensure fair play"* No there aren't.

Comment: Maybe badges or awards of some kind that are given for a certain number of questions being answered in a particular language would be better. Like 200 questions answered on php (or something). That might be a happy middleground. But like all the badges could also of course be abused. Might give some more love to the less visited languge tags though

Answer (score 21):

Meaningfully testing a person's programming ability using automated tests is hard. This part of the process should better be left to those who are actually doing the recruiting.

- There are a *lot* of technologies out there and building even a basic skills test for each of them would likely be very expensive for SO
- Basic skills tests can be gamed (prevent a *programmer* from clicking outside the window, lol) and do nothing to demonstrate higher-level skills - problem-solving, deep thinking, analytic abilities, people skills, etc. What if a candidate is a great analytical thinker, but can't for the life of them memorize SQL commands and has to look them up all the time, because it's not that frequently needed in their role? That hardly makes them worthless candidates per se. What about architect level people whose abilities you can't test in a multiple-choice questionnaire *at all*?

Let's not get into this.

Also, some would argue that SO careers already *has* that skills test - in the form of your SO profile. It's a track record of your questions and answers, from which it is easy to derive how much you know.

Comment: Then how do you explain companies like Odesk doing it?

Comment: @user5680735 It's more aligned with their focus, and them doing it is hardly proof that it works / is a good idea for SO careers anyways.

Comment: @user Odesk is catering to a totally different audience from Careers. On Careers, the people hiring are experienced recruiters in the majority of cases, who can weed out duds quickly. They do that all day already. On Odesk, you may be looking for a freelancer to build your web site / blog / online store, but you (as the customer) may lack the knowledge to evaluate candidates' abilities. Also there's a difference between a job (with a work contract, a candidate showing up in the office, etc.) and a quick freelance job. It's way more difficult to fake your way in with the former than the latter.

Comment: @user5680735 How do you explain all the companies that **aren't** doing it? Just because you can name some that are doesn't mean it's necessarily a good idea.